# jQuery queue function just execute once

Tags: jquery, css

How can i return element to its position after execute animated.css animations?
I use this code but it just executed once and then classes didnt remove for next time

```
$(".stitch")
    .hover( function () {
        $(this).addClass("animated hinge");
    } )
    .delay( 5000 )
    .queue( function () {
        $(this).removeClass("animated hinge").dequeue();
    } );
```

I tried dequeue and next but not working.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you looking to remove the class after the animation has finished?

Comment: yes, class didnt remove for 2nd time, also i put alert and queue didnt execute

Comment: Animate.css has a solution for this in their documentation which I have posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks hungerstar :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to remove the animation classes after the animation has completed you can use the simple jQuery plugin code take from the documentation for [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).

```js
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function (animationName) {
        var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
});

var $me = $( '#me' );

$me.hover( function () {
  $me.animateCss( 'hinge' );
} );
```

```css
@import url( 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="me">Hello</div>
```